# Android Manifest support mobile devices screens only

Tags: java, android, google-play

I have a problem in dealing with `<supports-screens>` tag in the Android manifest. I have 2 APKs for the same application,one is destined for tablet devices while the other is destined for all other devices. I mean by tablet devices starting from 7 inches till 10 inches. I published the Tablet's APK successfully with versionCode 3, and it appeared only to tablets through the following tag

```
    <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Now, I am trying to upload the mobile device's APK with versionCode 4 through the following

```
    <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:largestWidthLimitDp="590"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

But I keep getting the following error after uploading the APK

[image]

Keeping in mind that largeScreens can either be tablets or handheld devices according to the following Android documentation:

[image]

Please can anyone help?

Comment: Assuming the latest versioncode that you've uploaded is 4, try uploading the Tablet version (versioncode 3) with a new versioncode=5. It has to do with the supported API Levels i.e. in order to have multiple APKs for an app, Google Play requires the most API Levels supported APK with lower versioncode while it's subset to have higher versioncode. Try it let me know.